# Recognize IRC color characters on Android

Tags: android, special-characters, irc

Im developing an irc client on android and want to set the color and style messages as they are sent.
The characters that identifies things such as color, bold and underline are like \u0002, \u001f, and \u000301 (\u0003+color in 2 chars).
If i do

```
char c = msg.charAt(i);
if(c=='\u0003'){
    //is a color special character
}
```

will it work on android?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

charAt() only returns one character, right? So it wouldn't ever match a string. One way I could imagine doing this is splitting a string based on the color - for example:

```
String splitMsg[] = msg.split("\u0003")
if (splitMsg.length() > 0) { //If the string actually has that character in it
  //Set splitMsg[1] color to whatever
}
```

You could also use msg.lastIndexOf("\u0003"), which would return the index of the 3 in that string and you could turn the substring after that whatever color you want.